# grep with separate options for multiple patterns

Tags: grep

I would like to apply the print only-matching option (`-o`) to one pattern specified by `grep -e 'PATTERN'` syntax, while another similarly specified pattern should display the whole line containing the match (i.e. default behavior). Can this be done?

Comment: Enclose one pattern between anchors `^.*` and `.*$`.

Comment: @jimmij, @nasir-riley while this would solve this particular instance of the problem, it doesnt seem to generalize to the situation described in the question title, e.g. if you would like to `--invert-match` one expression while print `--only-matching` another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will select only the matches for one pattern and the full line for another:

```
grep -oe 'this_pattern' -e '^.*that_pattern.*$' file
```

This also works and makes it a bit cleaner:

```
grep -Eoe 'this_pattern|^.*that_pattern.*$' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Not today.

The [current source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c#n76) for GNU grep indicates a global "only_matching" variable which is toggled on by the `-o` option. That variable is used during the printing process to determine how much of the line to print.

Comment: tried to upvote this as useful, but apparently need to improve my rep first :)